# Local Notification some specific day ngCordova IONIC

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications

I am developing an application with ionic , in which I need the user to program the hours and days in which must reach a reminder.

I am using the plugin Cordova local notifications , as I can create a notification for example be repeated every Monday or the day that the user place ?

I’m around trying to do this but does not work

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());
date.setHours(15);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);

cordova.plugins.localNotifications.schedule({
 id: 1,
 title: 'Daily Training Reminder',
 at: date,
 every: 'Monday'
});
```

Can anyone help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.localNotification.schedule({
     "id": Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000)),
     'title': 'Some Title',
     'trigger': {
           'every': {
              'weekday': 1,
              'hour': 10,
              'minute': 40
           }, 
           'count': 1
         }
});
```

Also i have used Ionic [LocalNotificaiton](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/)

here `hour` is 24-hour based `minute` is minute `count` is count of notification

so it will receive a notification on Monday at 10:40

`weekday:1` (Monday)

`weekday:2` (Tuesday)...

Answer (score -1):

The ionic wrapper is outdated and doesn't work so use the cordova plugin and then do something like

```
declare let cordova: any; //above export class
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
       title: "title",
       text: "body",
       trigger: { at: new Date(),every: 'day', count: 1 }
});
```

Comment: But the use case is to call it every *Monday*

Comment: then use 'weekday' instead of 'day' same number because 1 - 7 Monday to Sunday

Comment: @Lenoid Can you help me with the syntax